# Postman assertion for string that contains dynamic value as a substring

Tags: javascript, postman, assertion

I am trying to add an assertion to my postman response-
new task item added with TaskId : ce0bb7ee-b31d-47c7-afb8-d65c371870d9 
which has a dynamic guid value in. The assertion fails for the dynamic substring. Please advise

```
var responseText = pm.response.text();

ResponseTextContains = (text) => {
    pm.test("Body contains " + text , function () {
    pm.expect(responseText).to.include(text);
    });
};

ResponseTextContains("new task item added with TaskId : ce0bb7ee-b31d-47c7-afb8-d65c371870d9");
```

I expect that my assertion should pass considering the dynamic substring value

Comment: Can you please add a example response? Is it JSON oder plaintext?

Comment: Why don't you just use `pm.expect(responseText).to.include('new task...TaskId :');`? Do you need to validate the id format? (I guess it is uuid)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't need to validate the id format just want to check that a uuid is present. My response is plain text,example -  new task item added with TaskId : 7a863af5-766b-4f0d-b873-aeffab2ba2f9

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that a uuid is provided, why not use a regex to do a match of the format? That way you get 2-in-1 (uuid is present AND it matches the format.)
If not, then you have previous answers that recommend using partial match of the response.